# PHP Redirect loads current page

Tags: php

I am doing a redirect using the below code. The issue is that when the redirect code is executed, it loads the current page again and then eventually redirects to the new page.

I dont want it to reload the current page and to redirect automatically to the new page.

Thanks

I have written code for the redirect and debugged the code.

```
function util_redirect ($page)
{
    ob_start();
        header("Location: " . $page,true);
    ob_end_flush();
        die();
}
```

Expected: Redirect to new page
Actual: reloads the current page and then redirects

Comment: the header() function happens before any other output?

Comment: `header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location:". $page); `

Comment: 302 didnot work

Comment: actually i'm not sure what happen as you said in the question *"I dont want it to reload the current page and to redirect automatically to the new page"*, is it you want a [hyperlink](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) (`<a>` element) that send you directly to the page without doing a request to the server first? as far as i know, redirect using `Location` header will always need you to do some request, then the browser sees the `Location` header from your web application, then sends you to the new url provided by `Location` header..

Comment: Yes i want it to goto new location but before going to the new location its reloading the current page and hence the php code i have in the page is being executed twice.

Comment: Put your code after `util_redirect();` so that it doesn't execute twice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to go to your url with new tab.

```
echo '<script>window.open("your url", "_blank");</script>';
```

Comment: this didnot work and just doesnot forward to next page